# Text Area not triggering value change event when set from Java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to add some CSS classes on Text Area that is pre-filled by Java Script. But some how even after triggering the trigger(input) event there is no value that I am able to validate and set my css classes.

The code keeps going to Value not set mode. When I try to print the value, its empty. How to listen to values and validate there?

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          document.getElementById('text_area').value = 'This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.';
          $('textarea').trigger('input');

<!-- checking if there is autofill set and checking if there is value in autofill -->

    $('[autofill]').each(function(){
                alert($(this).attr('autofill'), this);
                if($(this).attr('autofill') == "on"){
                    var value = $(this).val() ? true : false;
                    if (value) {
                        alert("value set");
                    } else {
                        alert("value not set");
                    }
                }
            });
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-control-mds label-up five twelve--tablet twelve-phone push-top-2">
      <textarea id="text_area" data-autoresize class="input-control   auto-expand" name="text_area" required autofill="on"></textarea>
      <label for="text_area" class="label-control">Text Area</label>
    </div>
```

JSBIN link

https://jsbin.com/jafovog/edit?html,js

Comment: What your condition you comparing to? Var value will always be true as per my thinking . Should not it be like var value = this.val == something ? True : false

Comment: I am ok with any value, if there is any value I need to highlight that field in css.

Answer (score 0):

To put the value inside `textarea` element, instead of this:

```
document.getElementById('text_area').value = 'This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.';
```

**DO this:**

```
document.getElementById('text_area').innerHTML= 'This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.';
```

And to retrieve the value of textarea, instead of this:

```
var value = $(this).val() ? true : false;
```

**DO this:**

```
var value = $(this).html() ? true : false;
```

**EDIT:**

I have **[edited your JSBIN demo](https://jsbin.com/kanilefula/edit?html,js,output)**. Here is the code:

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      document.getElementById('email').value = 'bala@mindlens.com.sg';
      document.getElementById('text_area1').innerHTML = '1234This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.This can be a long text and it is not auto expanding? it shoudl auto expand.';

      $('textarea').trigger('input');
      $('textfield').trigger('change');


      $('[autofill]').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('autofill'), this);
        if ($(this).attr('autofill') == "on") {
          var value = ($(this).html() !== "") ? true : false;
          alert("value = "+$(this).html());
          console.log("value", value);
          if (value) {
            console.log("value set");alert("value set");
          } else {
            console.log("value not set");alert("value not set");
          }
        }
  });
});
```

Comment: No effect.. it still has no value set.. @Rahul

Comment: I have edited your JSBIN demo. and I have edited my answer. Please let me know if you still have any issues.